# Inserir títulos dos itens na lateral carousel bootstrap

Tags: html, css3, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, carousel

Estou tentando fazer um carousel usando o framework **bootstrap**, mas estou com dificuldades para inserir os títulos dos itens carousel na lateral e inserir uma borda por cima como na imagem abaixo.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Carousel Bootstrap

```
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .hide-bullets {
            list-style:none;
            margin-left: -40px;
            margin-top:20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container">
            <div id="main_area">
                    <!-- Slider -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
                            <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six"></div>
                                        </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
                                        </a>                                
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-4" id="carousel-text"></div>

                                <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
                                    <div id="slide-content-0">
                                        <h2>Titulo 1</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-1">
                                        <h2>Titulo 2</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-2">
                                        <h2>Titulo 3</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-3">
                                        <h2>Titulo 4</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-4">
                                        <h2>Titulo 5</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-5">
                                        <h2>Titulo 6</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/Slider-->

                    <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
                            <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                            <ul class="hide-bullets">
                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-2"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"></a>
                                </li>

                                <li class="col-sm-2">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six"></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                 
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                    interval: 5000
            });

            $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());

            //Handles the carousel thumbnails
           $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
                var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
                var id = parseInt(id);
                $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
            });


            // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
            $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                     var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                    $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
            });
    });

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Posta o que vc já tem de código HTML / CSS / JS. Assim fica melhor para te dar uma resposta precisa!

Comment: @hugocsl inclui o código no post

Comment: Cara para colocar o nome do lado das imagens é tranquilo, basta dividir em 12 col-sm-1 se quiser posto um Snippet de exemplo. Mesmo assim precisa fazer tratamento para ficar formatado direitinho em tamanhos de tela diferentes. Já esse quadrado por cima complica. Pq ele fica por cima dos outros elementos, ai vc não consegui clicar no que está abaixo! Tentei com Div, com ::after, e com SVG e nenhum deu certo.

Comment: @hugocsl Obrigado se você quiser passar um snippet de exemplo serei grato!

Answer (score 0):

Aqui tem um modelo com o texto ao lado de cada miniatura de imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**OBS1:** Você precisa formatar o `@medi`a para alinhar o texto em cada tamanho de tela. Você terá que customizar alguns CSS para ficar legal em todo tamanho de tela.

**OBS2:** Execute o Snippet em **"Página toda"** para ver o resultado

```js
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  
              $('#myCarousel').carousel({
                      interval: 5000
              });
  
              $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-0').html());
  
              //Handles the carousel thumbnails
             $('[id^=carousel-selector-]').click( function(){
                  var id = this.id.substr(this.id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
                  var id = parseInt(id);
                  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
              });
  
  
              // When the carousel slides, auto update the text
              $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function (e) {
                       var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');
                      $('#carousel-text').html($('#slide-content-'+id).html());
              });
      });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            .hide-bullets {
            list-style:none;
            margin-left: -40px;
            margin-top:20px;
            }
            .pic-name {
                line-height: 4.5rem;
            }
            #main_area {
                margin-top: 100px;
            }

        </style>

    </head>
    <body>


        <div class="container">
            <div id="main_area">
                    <!-- Slider -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-12" id="slider">
                            <!-- Top part of the slider -->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-8" id="carousel-bounding-box">
                                    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
                                        <!-- Carousel items -->
                                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                                            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=one"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=two"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=three"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=four"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=five"></div>

                                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                            <img src="http://placehold.it/770x300&text=six"></div>
                                        </div><!-- Carousel nav -->
                                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>                                       
                                        </a>
                                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>                                       
                                        </a>                                
                                        </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-sm-4" id="carousel-text"></div>

                                <div id="slide-content" style="display: none;">
                                    <div id="slide-content-0">
                                        <h2>Titulo 1</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-1">
                                        <h2>Titulo 2</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-2">
                                        <h2>Titulo 3</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-3">
                                        <h2>Titulo 4</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-4">
                                        <h2>Titulo 5</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>

                                    <div id="slide-content-5">
                                        <h2>Titulo 6</h2>
                                        <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
                                        <p class="sub-text">October 24 2014 - <a href="#">Leia Mais</a></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!--/Slider-->

                    <div class="row hidden-xs" id="slider-thumbs">
                            <!-- Bottom switcher of slider -->
                            <ul class="hide-bullets">
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-0"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=one"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 1</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=two"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 2</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-1"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=three"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 3</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-3"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=four"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 4</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-4"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=five"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 5</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a class="thumbnail" id="carousel-selector-5"><img src="http://placehold.it/170x100&text=six"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="col-sm-1">
                                    <a><span class="pic-name">text 6</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>                 
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

*Sobre a linha por cima do Slider vai ficar complicado*, por que é um elemento que fica por cima dos outros, com isso impossibilita o clique nos elementos que está estão por baixo. Tentei com `div`, `::after` e `svg` e nenhum deu certo usando só CSS.